# How do i show a certain excel worksheet from Userform button?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I need help with showing a specific Excel spreadsheet when the user clicks on a button called "Show in Excel".
When the user clicks i want the specific Excel worksheet to pop infront and show itself.
I have been looking for at long time now, and i need help :/

Sincerly,

Peyko.

This is what i have so far:

```
Private Sub CmdBtnExcel_Click()

Sheets("Sheet1").Show

End Sub
```

Comment: show us please what have you tried so far

Comment: try `Sheets("Sheet1").Select`

Comment: Or you can use `Sheets("Sheet1").Activate` if you want to select one sheet at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CmdBtnExcel_Click()

Sheets("Sheet1").visible = true
 Sheets("Sheet1").activate

End Sub
```

This will bring it 'infront'

Comment: Getting runtime error when using .show. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: You might need to show the userform as modeless for it to work, try it

Comment: Getting no errors, but nothing happens when i click the button now :/